# Arithmetic operation on null

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

```
LedgerId    AccountId   EntryType   Debit       Credit      
2               2           D       50000.00    NULL        
3               2           D       10000.00    NULL        
4               2           C       NULL        25000.00    
6               2           C       NULL        10000.00    
7               2           D       89000.00    NULL        
8               2           D       89000.00    NULL        
10              3           D       715871.00   NULL
```

Following query calculates the `Balance`:

```
Select Accounts.ID [AccountID],Name,AccountType [AccountType], SUM(Debit) - SUM(Credit) [Balance] FROM Accounts 
    join Dealers on Accounts.DealerId = Dealers.ID 
    join Ledger on Accounts.ID = Ledger.AccountId
    GROUP BY Accounts.ID, Name, AccountType
```

and it returns:

```
AccountID   Name    AccountType     Balance
2           Mateen  P               203000.00
3           Shery   P               NULL
```

expected output:

```
AccountID   Name    AccountType     Balance
2           Mateen  P               203000.00
3           Shery   P               715871.00
```

The `Balance` for Account 3 is Null, it returns `null` when it comes to subtract anything from `null`.

**For Example:**

```
select 5 - NULL
```

returns `NULL`.

**Question:** Now, how can I get the `Balance` instead of `NULL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`coalesce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190349(v=sql.120).aspx):

```
coalesce(sum(Debit), 0) - coalesce(sum(Credit), 0)
```

Comment: whats the diff b/w `isnull` and `coalesce`?

Answer (score 2):

try this with use of isnull(value,0) it will take null values as 0

```
Select Accounts.ID [AccountID],Name,AccountType [AccountType], 
 SUM(isnull( Debit,0)) - SUM(isnull(Credit,0)) isnull([Balance],0) as 
   Balance FROM Accounts 
     join Dealers on Accounts.DealerId = Dealers.ID 
     join Ledger on Accounts.ID = Ledger.AccountId
GROUP BY Accounts.ID, Name, AccountType
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with NULL values, SUM aggregate function ignores NULL values.
Coalesce function will replace it with 0 if NULL values found.

```
    Select Accounts.ID [AccountID],
           Name,
           AccountType [AccountType], 
           SUM(coalesce(Debit,0)) - SUM(coalesce(Credit,0)) [Balance] 
FROM       Accounts 
           join Dealers on Accounts.DealerId = Dealers.ID 
           join Ledger on Accounts.ID = Ledger.AccountId
           GROUP BY Accounts.ID, Name, AccountType
```

Comment: I think there's no difference for my scenario whether I check `NULL` before `SUM` or after `SUM`. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

Both Coalesce() and IsNULL() Function use to check Null Value

IsNULL(@variable,0)
Coalesce(@Variable,0)